# Sample class ratio vs. real world class ratio

Tags: classification, sampling, random-forest, ratio, gis

I am using RandomForest to generate a model to detect burned forest areas based on the reflectance values of satellite imagery. The burned area accounts, on average, for 10% of the pixels in my images, meaning i have a real world ratio of 1 burned area to 9 non burned. A random sample of 10.000 observations has led me into approximately that same ratio. The model leads into an overall good accuracy, but most of it comes from correctly classifying the more frequent class (non burn), while the less frequent (burn) is showing terrible accuracy.

I believe i could try to solve that problem through cost sensitive classification, but here is what i want to know: can i approach this by simply extracting an equal amount of random observations from each class and generating a sample with a 1:1 ratio?